# Agrupar elementos de una lista según sus diferentes tipos

Tags: python, lista

El frontend me regresa

`itemcompuesto=[['20', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['16', '1', '1'], ['10', '1', '1'], ['11', '1', '2'], ['15', '1', '3'], ['19', '1', '2'], ['17', '1', '1'], ['18', '1', '2'], ['21', '1', '3'], ['26', '1', '3'], ['40', '1', '1'], ['41', '1', '2'], ['42', '1', '3'], ['34', '1', '4'], ['23', '1', '4'], ['29', '1', '5'], ['30', '1', '5'], ['31', '1', '6'], ['33', '1', '7']]`

la idea aqui es agrupar los elementos en su respectiva lista

`resultadoDeseado=[['20', '16', '1', '1'], ['16', '10', '1', '1'], ['16', '11', '1', '2'], ['16', '15', '1', '3'], ['20', '19', '1', '2'], ['19', '17', '1', '1'], ['19', '18', '1', '2'], ['19', '21', '1', '3'], ['20', '26', '1', '3'], ['26', '40', '1', '1'], ['26', '41', '1', '2'], ['26', '42', '1', '3'], ['26', '34', '1', '4'], ['26', '23', '1', '4'], ['20', '29', '1', '5'], ['20', '30', '1', '5'], ['20', '31', '1', '6'], ['20', '33', '1', '7']]`

como se define el tipo según las funciones `getCaja`, `getKit` y `getItem` de momento

`item armado::  [('20', '16', '1', '1'), ('16', '10', '1', '1'), ('16', '11', '1', '2'), ('16', '15', '1', '3'), ('20', '19', '1', '2'), ('20', '17', '1', '1'), ('20', '18', '1', '2'), ('20', '21', '1', '3'), ('20', '26', '1', '3'), ('20', '40', '1', '1'), ('20', '41', '1', '2'), ('20', '42', '1', '3'), ('20', '34', '1', '4'), ('20', '29', '1', '5'), ('20', '30', '1', '5'), ('20', '31', '1', '6')]`

obtengo ese resultado, el "problema" surge al encontrar el siguiente **kit** en la lista de `itemcompuesto` ya que no logro saber a que caja pertenece `_caja = getCaja(kits[0][0])` agrega el elemento "bien" porque se toma el primer elemento, el problema surgue cuando, en vez de ser la caja 20, es la 47, es decir, cuando se duplican los elementos de `itemcompuesto` y en lugar de '20', se cambia a '47'. Ahí, siempre va ser `('20', '19', '1', '2')` en lugar de `('47', '19', '1', '2')` y naturalmente lo mismo ocurre con el resto de kits e item. Siempre se asigna la caja, y no el item correspondiente

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
def getCaja(item):
    listacajas=['20', '47']
    if(item in listacajas):
        return item
    else:
        return None

def getKit(item):
    listakits=['16', '19', '26', '29', '30', '31', '20', '33']
    if(item in listakits):
        return item
    else:
        return None

def getItem(item):
    listaItems=['10', '11', '15', '17', '18', '21', '27', '28', '32', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46']
    if(item in listaItems):
        return item
    else:
        return None
def Item():
    itemcompuesto=[['20', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['16', '1', '1'], ['10', '1', '1'], ['11', '1', '2'], ['15', '1', '3'], ['19', '1', '2'], ['17', '1', '1'], ['18', '1', '2'], ['21', '1', '3'], ['26', '1', '3'], ['40', '1', '1'], ['41', '1', '2'], ['42', '1', '3'], ['34', '1', '4'], ['23', '1', '4'], ['29', '1', '5'], ['30', '1', '5'], ['31', '1', '6'], ['33', '1', '7']]
    print('list: {}\nTAM: {}'.format(itemcompuesto, len(itemcompuesto)))

    running = True
    idx = 0
    itemcomp=[]
    kits=[]
    while running:
        thiselem = itemcompuesto[idx]
        idx = (idx + 1) % len(itemcompuesto)
        # print('indice: ', idx)
        nextelem = itemcompuesto[idx]
        itemAct=thiselem[0]
        print('THIS element: %s %s'%(thiselem, itemAct))
        itemSig=nextelem[0]
        print('NEXT element:: %s %s'%(nextelem, itemSig))
        if(getCaja(itemAct) != None):
            print('Es caja: ', itemAct)
            if(getKit(itemSig) != None):
                print('Es kit: ', itemSig)
                kits.append((itemAct, nextelem[0], nextelem[1], nextelem[2]))
                print('caja armada: ', kits)
            elif(getItem(itemSig) != None):
                    print('Es Item: ', itemSig)
                    kits.append((kits[len(kits)-1][0], nextelem[0], nextelem[1], nextelem[2]))
                    print('item armado: ', kits)
        elif(getKit(itemAct) != None):
            print('Es kit:: ', itemAct)
            _caja = getCaja(kits[0][0])
            kits.append((_caja, thiselem[0], thiselem[1], thiselem[2]))
            kits = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(kits))
            print('item armado:: ', kits)
            # elimina duplicados y manitiene el orden
        elif(getItem(itemAct) != None):
            print('Es Item::: ', itemAct)
            if(len(kits)==1):
                _kit = getKit(kits[len(kits)-1][1])
                print('último elemt\t', _kit)
                kits.append((_kit, thiselem[0], thiselem[1], thiselem[2]))
            else:
                _kit = getKit(kits[len(kits)-1][0])
                print('último elemt\t', _kit)
                kits.append((_kit, thiselem[0], thiselem[1], thiselem[2]))
            print('item armado::: ', kits)
            kits = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(kits))
        if(idx==len(itemcompuesto)-1):
            running = False

Item()
```

Resultado deseado de `itemcompuesto` a `resultadoDeseado`

```py
resultadoDeseado=[['20', '16', '1', '1'], ['16', '10', '1', '1'], ['16', '11', '1', '2'], ['16', '15', '1', '3'], ['16', '17', '1', '4'], ['19', '1', '1'], ['19', '18', '1', '1'], ['19', '21', '1', '2'], ['19', '27', '1', '1']]

resultadoDeseado=[['20', '16', '1', '1'], ['16', '10', '1', '1'], ['16', '11', '1', '2'], ['16', '15', '1', '3'], ['20', '19', '1', '2'], ['19', '17', '1', '1'], ['19', '18', '1', '2'], ['19', '21', '1', '3'], ['20', '26', '1', '3'], ['26', '40', '1', '1'], ['26', '41', '1', '2'], ['26', '42', '1', '3'], ['26', '34', '1', '4'], ['26', '23', '1', '4'], ['20', '29', '1', '5'], ['20', '30', '1', '5'], ['20', '31', '1', '6'], ['20', '33', '1', '7']]
```

Los `resultadoDeseado` son pruebas de salida, naturalmente estos varian según el `itemcompuesto`

##### Como se conforma la lista

En si, es una lista global, en donde cada elemento tiene 4 "subelementos"

los elementos de caja: `cajaA,kit1,numA,numB`

los elementos de kit: `kit1,item1,numIA,numIB`, `kit1,item2, numIA,numIB`...

si hay otra caja sería: `cajaB,kit1,numA,numB`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def getCaja(item):
    listacajas=['20', '47']
    for i in range(len(item)-1,-1, -1):
        # print(f'getCaja:\tIndice: {i}\tElemento:\t{item[i]}')
        if(type(item[i])==tuple):
            for a in range(len(item[i])-1,-1, -1):
                # print(f'getCaja::\tIndice: {a}\tElemento:\t{item[i][a]}')
                if(item[i][a] in listacajas):
                    return item[i][a]
        elif(item[i] in listacajas):
            return item[i]
            

def getKit(item):
    listakits=['16', '19', '26', '29', '30', '31', '33']
    for i in range(len(item)-1,-1,-1):
        if(type(item[i])==tuple):
            for a in range(len(item[i])-1,-1, -1):
                # print(f'getCaja::\tIndice: {a}\tElemento:\t{item[i][a]}')
                if(item[i][a] in listakits):
                    return item[i][a]
        elif(item[i] in listakits):
            return item[i]


def getItem(item):
    listaItems=['10', '11', '15', '17', '18', '21', '27', '28', '32', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46']
    for i in range(len(item)-1,-1,-1):
        if(type(item[i])==tuple):
            for a in range(len(item[i])-1,-1, -1):
                # print(f'getCaja::\tIndice: {a}\tElemento:\t{item[i][a]}')
                if(item[i][a] in listaItems):
                    return item[i][a]
        elif(item[i] in listaItems):
            return item[i]

def Item():
    itemcompuesto=[['20', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['16', '10', '1'], ['11', '1', '2'], ['15', '1', '3'], ['17', '1', '4'], ['19', '1', '1'], ['18', '1', '1'], ['21', '1', '2'], ['27', '1', '3']]
    # itemcompuesto=[['20', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['16', '1', '1'], ['10', '1', '1'], ['11', '1', '2'], ['15', '1', '3'], ['19', '1', '2'], ['17', '1', '1'], ['18', '1', '2'], ['21', '1', '3'], ['26', '1', '3'], ['40', '1', '1'], ['41', '1', '2'], ['42', '1', '3'], ['34', '1', '4'], ['23', '1', '4'], ['29', '1', '5'], ['30', '1', '5'], ['31', '1', '6'], ['33', '1', '7']]

    # itemcompuesto=[['20', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['16', '1', '1'], ['10', '1', '1'], ['38', '1', '2'], ['36', '1', '3']]
    print('list: {}\nTAM: {}'.format(itemcompuesto, len(itemcompuesto)))

    running = True
    idx = 0
    itemcomp=[]
    kits=[]
    while running:
        thiselem = itemcompuesto[idx]
        idx = (idx + 1) % len(itemcompuesto)
        # print('indice: ', idx)
        nextelem = itemcompuesto[idx]
        itemAct=thiselem#[0]
        print('THIS element: %s'%(thiselem))
        itemSig=nextelem#[0]
        print('NEXT element:: %s'%(nextelem))
        caja=getCaja(itemAct)
        if(caja != None):
            # print('Es caja: ', itemAct)
            kit=getKit(itemSig)
            if(kit != None):
                # print('Es kit: ', itemSig)
                kits.append((caja, nextelem[0], nextelem[1], nextelem[2]))
                print('caja armada: ', kits)
            elif(getItem(itemSig) != None):
                    # print('Es Item: ', itemSig)
                    kits.append((caja, nextelem[0], nextelem[1], nextelem[2]))
                    print('item armado: ', kits)
        elif(getKit(itemAct) != None):
            # print('Es kit:: ', itemAct)
            #caja = getCaja(kits[len(kits)-1][0])
            caja = getCaja(kits)
            kits.append((caja, thiselem[0], thiselem[1], thiselem[2]))
            # kits = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(kits))
            print('item armado:: ', kits)
            # elimina duplicados y manitiene el orden
        elif(getItem(itemAct) != None):
            kit = getKit(kits)
            print('último kit:\t', kit)
            kits.append((kit, thiselem[0], thiselem[1], thiselem[2]))
            print('item armado::: ', kits)
            #kits = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(kits))
        if(idx==len(itemcompuesto)-1):
            if(getKit(itemSig) != None):
                # print('Es kit:: ', itemAct)
                #caja = getCaja(kits[len(kits)-1][0])
                caja = getCaja(kits)
                kits.append((caja, nextelem[0], nextelem[1], nextelem[2]))
                # kits = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(kits))
                print('item armado:: ', kits)
                # elimina duplicados y manitiene el orden
            elif(getItem(itemSig) != None):
                kit = getKit(kits)
                print('último kit:\t', kit)
                kits.append((kit, nextelem[0], nextelem[1], nextelem[2]))
                print('item armado::: ', kits)
                #kits = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(kits))
            running = False
    
    resultadoDeseado=[('20', '16', '10', '1'), ('16', '11', '1', '2'), ('16', '15', '1', '3'), ('16', '17', '1', '4'), ('20', '19', '1', '1'), ('19', '18', '1', '1'), ('19', '21', '1', '2'), ('19', '27', '1', '3')]

    #resultadoDeseado=[('20', '16', '1', '1'), ('16', '10', '1', '1'), ('16', '11', '1', '2'), ('16', '15', '1', '3'), ('20', '19', '1', '2'), ('19', '17', '1', '1'), ('19', '18', '1', '2'), ('19', '21', '1', '3'), ('20', '26', '1', '3'), ('26', '40', '1', '1'), ('26', '41', '1', '2'), ('26', '42', '1', '3'), ('26', '34', '1', '4'), ('26', '23', '1', '4'), ('20', '29', '1', '5'), ('20', '30', '1', '5'), ('20', '31', '1', '6'), ('20', '33', '1', '7')]
    
    #resultadoDeseado=[('20', '16', '1', '1'), ('16', '10', '1', '1'), ('16', '38', '1', '2'), ('16', '36', '1', '3')]

    print('tam. resul: %s tam. kits: %s'%(len(resultadoDeseado), len(kits)))
    valido = True
    for indice, elem in enumerate(resultadoDeseado):
        print('resultadoDeseado:\t{}\nsalida:\t{}'.format(kits[indice],elem))
        if(kits[indice]==elem):
            print(f"En {indice} tenemos a {elem}: {valido}")
        else:
            valido = False
            print(f"En {indice} tenemos {valido}")
    
Item()
```

aunque repite el primer elemento